# error: expected declaration or statement at end of input in c

Tags: c

```
void mi_start_curr_serv(void){
#if 0
 //stmt
#endif    
}
```

I'm getting an error as "error: expected declaration or statement at end of input" in my compiler. I could not find any error with the above function. Please help me to understand this error.

Comment: `;` (And a few other characters to make SO happy)

Comment: If that's the exact code, then no idea. That's an empty function and should compile without problems. Is there anything else you're not showing? :P

Comment: Now, if there's more code, you may find there's some `}` missing somewhere...

Comment: Does your C compiler accept C99/C++ `//...EOL` comments?  Do you have a newline as the last character in the file?

Comment: @Jonathan, I too thought the // comment was a possible culprit.  But because it is #if-0'd out, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @abelenky: on the face of it, there shouldn't be any issue.  It's an odds-on bet the trouble is in other code that precedes this code, but eliminate the possible...

Comment: I often copy and paste method signatures to the top of my code when forward declaring. I remember a couple of instances where I forgot to replace the '{' with ';' in the forward declaration. You may want to look there too (for future people seeing this post).

Comment: 85K views for a post is a very good thing ! OMG !!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Normally that error occurs when a `}` was missed somewhere in the code, for example:

```
void mi_start_curr_serv(void){
    #if 0
    //stmt
    #endif
```

would fail with this error due to the missing `}` at the end of the function. The code you posted doesn't have this error, so it is likely coming from some other part of your source.

Comment: Most probably an unbalanced `}` at the end of `main`. Otherwise there's a high chance of other errors.

Comment: Thanks.. I missed a } closing bracket in another function which affected this function. Thanks for correctly pointing it out.

Comment: had the same error. A second pair of "eyes" is always better, even when they come from the internets!

Comment: For me, it was from an include file where I wrote `void foo(void) {` instead of `void foo(void);` because of copy-paste...

Comment: Correct is most probably "}"

Comment: A missing RETURN STATEMENT can also cause this error! I had the error, all brackets were in place fine, and I added "return;" to the bottom of my function and it went away. This was using gcc on a void-return function.

Comment: Emacs users: M-x check-parens, very valuable!

Comment: When looking for an unbalanced `{` don't forget any included header files.

Answer (score 5):

For me this problem was caused by a missing ) at the end of an if statement in a function called by the function the error was reported as from.  Try scrolling up in the output to find the first error reported by the compiler.  Fixing that error may fix this error.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have syntax error.
You most likely forgot to put a `}` or `;` somewhere above this function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's quite unclear for me. Can you, please, edit your answer to clarify ? We can help you formatting it, if required.

Comment: For me I can say it was a missing `}`, but not on the line number where the compiler was pointing at.  So others be weary of that.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a missing } bracket in a function called by the code where the error was reported. Was also reported on code calling the function that called the function missing the }. So can be hard to find if you do not know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place a

> return 0;

on the end of your code or just erase the

> void

from your main function
I hope that I helped

Answer (score 0):

For me I just noticed that it was my .h archive with a '{'. Maye that can help someone =)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who tries to run a mpi program and gets the error above, deleting commends right before or after these symbols `{` `}` seem to do the trick.

I have both kali and ubuntu wsl, in kali the program runs fine but in ubuntu i had to delete the comments in order for the program to run

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30626967)